# How can I build an RPM package in a Debian based system?

Tags: packaging, rpm, debian-based

I'd like to build packages using a build system (i.e. jenkins, travis, etc) but all I have are Ubuntu 12.04 VMs.

I've found this [1] instructions but mach does not support CentOS 7.0.

[1] http://blog.burghardt.pl/2008/12/how-to-build-rpm-packages-in-centos-chroot-on-debian/

Comment: Debian provides tools, but it's been a while (years) since I've seen them deliver a workable RPM configuration.

Comment: @ThomasDickey the RPMs built using `rinse` are working quite well (in my case at least).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found it! There is actually a tool called rinse: "Rinse is a simple tool which is designed to carry out the installation of a new RPM-based distribution".

```
rinse --distribution="centos-7" --directory="/tmp/centos-7"
```

http://collab-maint.alioth.debian.org/rinse/

Comment: While this seems to answer your _actual_ question - after all you're the author of the question - this does not answer the question you asked. That's, however, answered by the other answer which points out that `rpm` can be installed on Debian/Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 16):

http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/  <- rpm plugin for the maven build system

```
sudo apt-get install rpm # for Ubuntu
```

Check out the command that it installs called `rpmbuild`.